# Android: Click ListItem of ListView to replace a Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I have a `TabLayout` wherein I am showing 3 tabs each one as fragment. First tab loading first fragment which has a `ListView`. When I am clicking an item of `ListView` I want my First tab fragment to be replaced with a new Fragment containing details of item clicked.

Here is my implementation:
**my Activity's layoutout: dashboard.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ParentContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".interestingReads.InterestingReadsDashboard_Activity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/interestingReadsAppBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/interestingReadsToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/interestingReadsTabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyCustomSmallLettersTextAppearance"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/interestingReadsViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="165dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />


</FrameLayout>
```

**fragment_rss_feeds.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout111"
    tools:context=".interestingReads.RSSFeedsTab">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/rssFeedsListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@android:color/black"
        android:dividerHeight="8dp"
        android:background="@color/diffBackgroundWhite"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

**rss_item_list_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rssFeeds_LL_list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:clickable="true"
    >
<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="6dp"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/rssFeeds_Image_list_view"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:padding="0dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="7dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rssFeeds_Title_list_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rssFeeds_Description_list_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**RSSFeedsTab.java**

```
public class RSSFeedsTab extends ListFragment implements  OnItemClickListener {
.
.
.
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
.
.
.    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View RootView =  getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_rssfeeds_tab, container, false); //pass the correct layout name for the fragment
        final ListView RSSFeedsItemLV = (ListView) RootView.findViewById(R.id.rssFeedsListView);
        final LinearLayout RSSFeeds_SingleItem_LL = (LinearLayout) RootView.findViewById(R.id.rssFeeds_LL_list_view);
.
.
.
        SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.rss_item_list_row, from, to){
            @Override
            public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
            {
                View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                final int finalposition = position;
                final LinearLayout RSSFeed_singleItem=(LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.rssFeeds_LL_list_view);

                RSSFeed_singleItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                         Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Link:==>"+localLinkArray[finalposition],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        FragmentTransaction trans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        trans.replace(R.id.rssFeeds_LL_list_view, new ReadSingleRSSItem());

                        trans.commit();

                    }
                });
                return v;
            }
        };
        setListAdapter(simpleAdapter);
        RSSFeedsItemLV.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    }
```

With the above implementation, I am achieving this much:
[image]
Here, inside `onClick` I am trying to replace my Full(`fragment_rss_feeds.xml`) fragment with a new fragment.
For this, I am trying:

```
FragmentTransaction trans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            trans.replace(R.id.rssFeeds_LL_list_view, new ReadSingleRSSItem());
```

which only replaces a single item of `ListView` as showen in snapshot.
If I use `R.id.relativeLayout111` instead of `R.id.rssFeeds_LL_list_view` in `trans.replace` it gives me error:

> No view found for id 0x7f0900b7 (id/relativeLayout111)

Can somebody please help me, how effectively I shall use `trans.replace` in my case?
Also, how I can access id `relativeLayout111` in `trans.replace` ?

Thanks in Advance !!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a container in your parent layout, in this case, which is the activity containing your tabs. For example, a Framelayout mentioned below

```
       <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/detail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

then you need to put your RSS detail fragment in this container by using

```
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        trans.replace(R.id.detail, new ReadSingleRSSItem()).commit();
```

Comment: Hi @Fahad, I used `FrameLayout` instead of `CoordinatorLayout` and using `trans.replace(R.id.detail, new ReadSingleRSSItem())` as suggested. 

It is not removing my full `ListView` as well as showing up the `ReadSingleRSSItem`.

Comment: Hi @Fahad: Can you please suggest, how I can access id `relativeLayout111` in `trans.replace` ?

Comment: Please make sure your detail FrameLayout is the child of parent container which includes details Framelayout and Tabs layout as well. @OmSao

Answer (score 0):

The problem with using `R.id.relativeLayout111` is that that one is inside of the **`Fragment`** which is placed **inside an activity, in some container.** The solution is to use that container's id instead.

You have not posted the code from your containing activity, so I cannot at this point know what that id is. Hopefully you understand what I'm saying. Basically just replace:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        trans.replace(R.id.rssFeeds_LL_list_view, new ReadSingleRSSItem());
```

With proper id!

Comment: Hi @Vucko, 
Thanks for the explaination.
I have added my Activity's layout responsible for full page containing 3 tabs.
The FrameLayout's id is `ParentContainer`

When I try `getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        trans.replace(R.id.ParentContainer, new ReadSingleRSSItem());`

It doesn't do anything :(
Am I missing something more.?

Comment: Hi @Vucko, can you please suggest, how I can access id `relativeLayout111` in `trans.replace` ?

Comment: You should try to use some other container rather than the outermost `FrameLayout`. Create another empty layout and try that in the activity. Make it below or above `ViewPager`.